# Building Custom Related List Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-events

I created a reusable lightning component that will act as a related list component. I want to handle add/remove event when the user makes changes from Edit Page (Settings-> Edit Page).

Example: I place my component under the Account's related tab

(Account's children: **Opportunity**, **Custom Object1**, **Custom Object2**, **Custom Object3**).

I added the Custom Lighting component 4 times for **Opportunity, Custom Object1, Custom Object2, Custom Object3** when the user removes **Custom Object1** from Edit Page, I want to handle an event that the user removed the custom lightning component which is a tie with **Custom Object1**.

Please let me know if you have any idea or suggestion.

Comment: Not sure, weather it will work or not, You can try using change event for the string type attribute.

Comment: How are you setting the object type on each instance of the custom lightning component. How are you seeing that the first Lightning Component is for **Opportunity**, the second for **Custom Object1** etc.

Comment: @sanketkumar change event will not work because of its fire when an attribute value change happens, Thanks for your input.
FYI: I'm thinking to try with destroy event.

Comment: @AyoolaOlapo yet I'm not able to find a way to store order but if I get my question's answer then I will know the order.
To keep which object have how many custom related lightning component, I'm maintaining a custom config object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my question answer using destroy handler and able to handle it.

Code:

```
<aura:handler name="destroy" value="{!this}" action="{!c.handleDestroy}"/>
```